# Sum all numbers touching symbols in 2D grid (Advent of Code 2023 Day 3, Part 1)

Tags: programming-challenge, rust

Please offer suggestions to my below Rust approach for solving AoC 2023 Day 3, Part 1. The code is functionally correct, so I'm interested in understanding how I could have solved it in a more idiomatic Rust way. In [quite](https://github.com/timvisee/advent-of-code-2023/blob/master/day03a/src/main.rs) [a few](https://github.com/Diggsey/aoc2023/blob/master/src/bin/day3a.rs) [other](https://github.com/alexhrao/aoc-2023/blob/main/src/day03.rs) solutions people heavily use iterators. Is this preferred?

For those not familiar with the Advent of Code Day 3, the below code is scanning a file three lines at a time (`prev`, `curr`, and `next`), attempting to find symbols in `curr`, and finding corresponding numbers adjacent to the symbols (a number is considered adjacent if a number touches a symbols, even diagonally). It then adds up all the adjacent numbers.

```rust
use std::fs::File;
use std::io::{self, BufRead, BufReader};
use regex::Regex;

/*
 * Given a line, find all numbers and insert an entry for every index in the 
 * range of that number (e.g., if 456 is found at range (3..6), the hashmap 
 * would have entries: {3: 456, 4: 456, 5: 456})
 */
fn find_nums(line: &str) -> HashMap<usize, i32> {
    let mut nums: HashMap<usize, i32> = HashMap::new();
    let re = Regex::new(r"\d+").expect("Invalid regex");

    for c in re.captures_iter(&line) {
        let m = c.get(0).expect("Match error");
        let num = m.as_str().parse::<i32>().expect("Invalid number");

        for i in m.range() {
            nums.insert(i, num);
        }
    }

    return nums;
}

fn check_neighbors(nums: &HashMap<usize, i32>, idx: usize) -> i32 {
    if let Some(val) = nums.get(&idx) {
        *val
    } else {
        let mut total = 0;
        if let Some(val) = nums.get(&(idx - 1)) {
            total += *val;
        }

        if let Some(val) = nums.get(&(idx + 1)) {
            total += *val;
        }

        total
    }
}


fn part_1() -> io::Result<()> {
    let file = File::open("./input")?;
    let reader = BufReader::new(file);

    let mut lines = reader.lines().flatten();
    let symbols_re = Regex::new(r"!|@|#|\$|%|\^|&|\*|\(|\)|\-|_|=|\+|/").expect("Invalid symbol regex");

    let mut total = 0;
    let mut prev_line = lines.next();
    let mut curr_line = lines.next();
    let mut next_line = lines.next();

    loop {
        if let (Some(prev), Some(curr), Some(next)) = (&prev_line, &curr_line, &next_line) {
            let prev_nums = find_nums(&prev);
            let curr_nums = find_nums(&curr);
            let next_nums = find_nums(&next);

            for c in symbols_re.captures_iter(&curr) {
                let m = c.get(0).expect("error");
                let idx = m.start();

                total += check_neighbors(&prev_nums, idx);
                total += check_neighbors(&curr_nums, idx);
                total += check_neighbors(&next_nums, idx);
            }

            prev_line = curr_line;
            curr_line = next_line;
            next_line = lines.next();
        } else {
            break;
        }
    }

    println!("Total: {}", total);
    Ok(())
}


fn main() {
    part_1();
}
```

Comment: I would say iterators are indeed considered more idiomatic in Rust.